# CreateSQLQuery(string) throws System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, sql, database, nhibernate

I'm trying to select data from a database with NHibernate v.5.1.3 in Visual Studio 2017.

I'm doing:

```
CreateSQLQuery("Select name from student").List<object[]> ()
```

and it throws a `System.ArgumentException`, because my query **has to return 1 column**.

With two or more columns it works properly.

Note that I cannot change the type of `List<object[]>` because it was used many times elsewhere in the code.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please include the actual exception in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you put `.List<object>()` instead? If it does, perhaps you can use that and convert to `List<object[]>` yourself before passing it on to other code?